# vCenter email notification has a semicolon/SMTP does not recognize it as a valid email address

Tags: email, smtp

Messages from vCenter has this header info:

```
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by (8.14.3/8.14.3/Submit) id u92F2su5032029;
    Sun, 2 Oct 2016 15:02:54 GMT
Date: Sun, 2 Oct 2016 15:02:54 GMT
Message-Id: <201610021502.u92F2su5032029@vCenter.firstriskadvisors.com>
To: alert@example.com;
From: vCenter@example.com
```

The `To` address has a semicolon and Windows SMTP does not recognize it as a valid email address:

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

       alert@example.com;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Apart from that the semicolon at the end of the email is an invalid syntax, i.e. Windows SMTP is right.

Comment: OK then this would be an issue with vCenter when it generates the notification email.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The obvious thing to do would be to remove the semicolon.

Comment: Its not as simple as just removing the semicolon. When you enter the email into the alarm for "send email notification" then hit save, vCenter adds a semicolon to the end of it no matter what.

Is there a way to remove that? Is there a config file that can be modified to fix this?

Comment: Seems like a bug in vCenter client IMHO. Have you tried the web client?